# Is there a way to make the code exploring Random Walk in 1 D space more optimal? (Without nested for loops)

Tags: python, optimization, nested-loops, random-walk

Trying to explore the **Random Walk** algorithm on **Infinite Line** and I'm looking for a way to make it **as optimal as possible**. Here is the code:

```py
import random
from collections import Counter

def run(initial_pos,iterations,trials):
    final_pos = []
    for i in range (0,trials):
        pos = initial_pos
        for j in range (0,iterations):
            if random.choice(["left","right"]) == "left":
                pos -= 1
            else:
                pos += 1
        final_pos.append(pos)
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

Variable **iterations** indicates the number of repetitions in a **single walk**.
While **trials** indicates the number of walks.

The runtime is satisfactory for **trials** and **iterations** equals  **10^4**
Hwever, increasing to **10^5** requires long waiting time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Low-hanging Fruit

First of all, let's get rid of those magic number and strings, and define some named constants:

```
RIGHT_NAME, LEFT_NAME = "right", "left"
RIGHT, LEFT = 1, -1
```

Now, we can rewrite the inner loop body to use those constants:

```
if random.choice([LEFT_NAME , RIGHT_NAME]) == LEFT_NAME:
    pos += LEFT
else:
    pos += RIGHT
```

Looking at that, two issues become apparent:

1. We're comparing strings for equality. That is unlikely to perform better than comparing small integers.
2. We have two pairs of constants representing the same concept (choice between left and right). We're repeating ourselves, and that's rarely a good thing.

Let's eliminate both of those issues by just using the integer constants `RIGHT` and `LEFT`. Let's also store the result of `random.choice` into a temporary to better see the next issue:

```
current_direction = random.choice([LEFT, RIGHT])
if current_direction == LEFT:
    pos += LEFT
else:
    pos += RIGHT
```

Now, we can see that `current_direction` can be either `RIGHT` or `LEFT`. If it's `LEFT`, then we add `LEFT` to `pos`, otherwise (the only other choice is `RIGHT`), we add `RIGHT` to `pos`. In other words:

```
current_direction = random.choice([LEFT, RIGHT])
if current_direction == LEFT:
    pos += current_direction   # current_direction is LEFT
else:
    pos += current_direction   # current_direction is RIGHT
```

Same thing happens in both branches, so let's get rid of the condition:

```
pos += random.choice([LEFT, RIGHT])
```

---

Here is our new starting point:

```
def run(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    final_pos = []
    RIGHT, LEFT = 1, -1
    for i in range(0, trials):
        pos = initial_pos
        for j in range(0, iterations):
            pos += random.choice([LEFT, RIGHT])
        final_pos.append(pos)
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

Now, if we look at the code critically (and having the low-level details of the byte-code and interpreter in mind -- the `dis` module helps here) we can see some other deficiencies:

1. The call [`range(0, trials)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is functionally identical to `range(trials)`. However, that redundant `0` means an extra opcode to push the constant onto the stack. We don't want to waste time on useless things, right?
2. In our inner-most loop, we're calling a function with argument `[LEFT, RIGHT]`. Python doesn't optimize such things, so that means we're creating the same list `iterations * trials` times. Even though it's just 3 opcodes, let's do it once, and then reuse the same list. We might as well make it a tuple, it doesn't need to change.
3. The class [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) supports [updates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update). So let's avoid the intermediate `final_pos` list, and update the `Counter` directly.
4. If we're hunting cycles, we can also note that a call to `random.choice` involves two opcodes (first get `random`, then find `choice`). We can cache the actual functions to call in local variables to avoid the extra step.

```
def run_v1(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    RIGHT, LEFT = 1, -1
    CHOICES = (RIGHT, LEFT)
   
    result = Counter()
    
    random_choice = random.choice
    result_update = result.update
    
    for i in range(trials):
        pos = initial_pos
        for j in range(iterations):
            pos += random_choice(CHOICES)
        result_update([pos])

    return result
```

Those initial changes only mean the code runs in about 90%-95% of the time needed by the original, but they give us a solid basis for further optimizations.

### Eliminating Inner Loop — Attempt 1

Right now our inner loop basically makes a sum of a list of random choices, offset by `initial_pos`. Let's use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead to generate `iterations` choices in one call, and the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to add them up.

```
def run_v2(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    RIGHT, LEFT = 1, -1
    CHOICES = (RIGHT, LEFT)
    
    result = Counter()
    
    random_choices = random.choices
    result_update = result.update
    
    for i in range(trials):
        result_update([initial_pos + sum(random_choices(CHOICES, k=iterations))])

    return result
```

This requires roughly 25% of the time required by `run_v1`.

### Eliminating Inner Loop — Attempt 2

The main problem with the previous version is that it ends up allocating a lot of intermediate Python objects (one for each choice). A more efficient way of using the memory would be to use numpy arrays and various functions the library provides. For example, we could use [`numpy.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) and the `sum` method of numpy arrays:

```
def run_v3(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    RIGHT, LEFT = 1, -1
    CHOICES = (RIGHT, LEFT)
    
    result = Counter()
    
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng_choice = rng.choice
    result_update = result.update
    
    for i in range(trials):
        result_update([initial_pos + rng_choice(CHOICES, size=iterations).sum()])
        
    return result
```

This version requires around 20% of the time required by `run_v2`.

### More Efficient Choices

Currently, the random choices require an indirect lookup to map into our desired set of `(1, -1)`. Let's observe that `iterations = right_count + left_count`. We already know the value of `iterations`, so as long as we know one of `right_count` or `left_count`, we can calculate the other.

Therefore `pos_offset = 2 * right_count - iterations`, and we can implement it as such:

```
def run_v4(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    result = Counter()
    
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng_choice = rng.choice
    result_update = result.update
    
    for i in range(0, trials):
        result_update([initial_pos + 2 * rng_choice(2, size=iterations).sum() - iterations])

    return result
```

This time it requires about 60%-90% of `run_v3`.

---

### Further Variations

Using `np.random.default_rng().integers` instead.

```
def run_v5a(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    final_pos = []
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng_integers = rng.integers
    for i in range(0, trials):
        pos = initial_pos + 2 * rng_integers(2, size=iterations).sum() - iterations
        final_pos.append(pos)
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

```
def run_v5b(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    final_pos = []
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng_integers = rng.integers
    for i in range(0, trials):
        pos = initial_pos + 2 * rng_integers(2, dtype=np.uint8, size=iterations).sum(dtype=np.int32) - iterations
        final_pos.append(pos)
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

---

Using more memory to eliminate the upper loop.

```
def run_v6a(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    final_pos = initial_pos + 2 * rng.integers(2, size=(trials, iterations)).sum(axis=1) - iterations
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

```
def run_v6b(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    final_pos = initial_pos + 2 * rng.integers(2, dtype=np.uint8, size=(trials, iterations)).sum(axis=1,
        dtype=np.int32) - iterations
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

---

As suggested by [Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%c3%a9r%c3%b4me-richard) sampling [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Applying math and using `np.random.binomial`.

```
def run_v7(initial_pos, iterations, trials):
    final_pos = initial_pos + 2 * np.random.binomial(iterations, 0.5, trials) - iterations
    return Counter(final_pos)
```

This runs in 1/4 second for 10^6 iterations and trials.

Answer (score 1):

~1000 times faster, takes just a few seconds for 10^5 trials and iterations.

```
def run(initial_pos,iterations,trials):
    final_pos = []
    for i in range (0,trials):
        right = random.getrandbits(iterations).bit_count()
        left = iterations - right
        pos = initial_pos + right - left
        final_pos.append(pos)
    return Counter(final_pos)
```